# Next.js "[WebpackGenerateSW] 'pwa' property is not expected to be here."

Tags: javascript, next.js, progressive-web-apps

I have next.js project and i want to add pwa support for my site. But after the "npm run build" i see [WebpackGenerateSW] 'pwa' property is not expected to be here" error. I add code block like this in next.config.js;

```
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");
const runtimeCaching = require("next-pwa/cache");
module.exports = withPWA({
pwa: {
  dest: "public",
  register: true,
  skipWaiting: true,
  runtimeCaching,
},
```

}),